# Select last character of a substring in regexp

Tags: regex, geojson

I'm trying to clean a huge geoJson datafile. I need to change the format of "text" field from

```
"text": "(2:Placename,Placename)"
```

to

```
"text": "Placename".
```

In Sublime text I managed to write a regular expression which enabled me to select and remove the first part leaving something like this:

```
"text": "Placename)"
```

With following regexp I can select the text above, but I need to narrow it down to the last character:

```
text\": \".*?\)
```

No matter what I can't figure out how to select the "`)`" character in the end of Placename string in the whole file and remove it. Note that the "Placename" here can be any place name, like New York, London etc.

I tried to build an expression where first part finds the text field, then ignores n-amount of characters until it finds the "`)`" character. 
After experimenting and Googling I couldn't find a solution here.

Comment: Show us your current regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the value of the second placemark field with the following regexp:

```
/"text": "+\(\d+:[^,]+,(.*?)\)/
```

Which will capture "Placename" in $1

More info on capturing parenthesis:  http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

The trick is to use the inverted character classes and to escape any parentheses you want to match.

HTH

Comment: I tried that in Sublime Text's regexp search and it seems to select "text": "(2:Alavieska,Alavieska) Problem is that I want to strip the first part and parenthesis away.

Comment: The expression will select the entire input text but value you want will be in the $1 variable.  Have a look at this online regexp evaluator:  http://mochi.github.io/mochikit/examples/mochiregexp/  I tried it with the above regexp and I get "Alalvieska" in my capture group

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if you are using a Unix system, but probably sed can do much of the work for you. It can interpret regular expressions, capture groups, and substitute by other groups of characters. I have tried an example with sed and the following sed command worked for me:

```
echo "\"text\": \"(2:Placename,Placename)\"" | sed -r 's/(\"text\": )\"\([[:digit:]]:[^0-9]+,([^0-9]+)\)\"/\1\"\2\"/g'
```

-r allows sed to interpret regular expressions. I am using parentheses to capture groups that I will use later in the substitution (e.g., a group for "text", and a group for the second placename). In the substitution part of sed, you can use groups by using \n where n is the group number that you want to used. This expression should help you to achieve your desired result.